# LyX is very slow to run on Windows

Tags: lyx, pdf

I am using LyX and for some reason it running very very slow. It was working fine but now it just stopped and i think it has to do with thepackages because i updated all but don't know exaclty which ones. can someone help I need to submit this week and dont know what to do ?

I have been waiting for over an hour and it is now loading into pdf

Comment: Try find the problem in the Messages Pane. Or export the file  to LaTeX and try to compile it in true LaTeX editor as Texworks to find/solve the errors. (the errors are showed at bottom, or edit last lines of the .log file). In the worse case, reducing your a copy of the LaTeX file to a  MWE in will help to locate the problem. Once you discover the problem, finish the work in the LateX version or repair the original .lyx file accordingly, but before, make a backup of the working file.

Comment: @Fran - How can I get the messages pane in LyX?

Comment: @Fran ok found them this is what I got:LyX could not be closed because documents are being processed by LyX.
18:59:29.541: Automatic save done.
19:04:29.620: Automatic save done.
20:52:38.093: Automatic save done.
20:57:37.482: Automatic save done.
20:58:09.756: (dialog-toggle progress)

Comment: That messages are the automatic backup that you set in Tools > Preferences > Document Handling > Backuck documents, every 5 minutes. Disable it for now. Check  what happen when you try to preview the  PDF (Ctrl+R)  or export to PDF in the File menu.

Comment: Fran's suggestions are great. Also make sure that you do not have the source code pane open.